Does TypeScript @peculiar/asn1-schema library always wraps objects into ASN.1 SEQUENCE?
I have following class in TypeScript:
import {
    AsnSerializer
} from '@peculiar/asn1-schema';

export class Element {
    constructor(
        public value: BigInteger
    ) {}

    public ToASN1(): ArrayBuffer {
        const element = new Element();
        element.value = new Uint8Array(this.value.toByteArray()).buffer;
        try {
            return new Uint8Array(AsnSerializer.serialize(element));
        } catch (error) {
            // handle
        }
    }

And the toASN1 method returns ASN.1 output as:
output ::= SEQUENCE {
    INTEGER
}

But I don't want that outer SEQUENCE to present and instead I only wish to have:
output ::= INTEGER

Is it achievable at all? I have found some links in the source code, but dunno is that indeed hardcoded into that library and therefore not changeable at all?

I don't know TypeScript, but I can tell you that if you are going to encode multiple values (looks like you are encoding an array) you're going to have some kind of enclosing tag in the ASN.1.

@Kevin definitely, but in this context we encode a single value, that is represented in bytes, i.e. BigInteger as byte array
